# Symfony2: Security/Routing Issue

Tags: security, symfony

Im using FOSFacebookBundle and FOSUserBundle on Symfony 2.1.3. Have some troubles with my security settings:

```
imports:    
  - { resource: facebookParameters.ini }

security:
  providers:
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
        id: my.facebook.user            
  firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: %facebookAppUrl%
            server_url: %facebookServerUrl%
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_fb_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        logout:
            handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
        anonymous:    true
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/game, roles: ROLE_FACEBOOK }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/gameinfos, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Path game should be secured by facebook login, path login and gameinfos should be free to all visitors. Ok login is fine, its accessable from everywhere, but gameinfos is not. It allways directs me to facebook when i call the path / route.
Where could be the problem?

Comment: Can't you access /gameinfos without logging in, or can't you access it after login?

Comment: i can't access it without logging in. as i defined IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY i thought that should be possible?

Comment: It could be the default target path. If your session has no URLs set, they will be routed to the facebook login route.

Comment: can you explain this a little more detailed? i dont know exactly what u mean.